# Panasonic DMC Gf6 w/HDMI output: can I connect directly to Mac Mini w/o converter?

Tags: webvideos, live, hdmi

Trying to figure out whether I can live stream a music performance at StageIt, Ustream, Livestream, etc. without buying any new hardware. Here's what I've got:

- Panasonic DMC GF6 camera w/HDMI and Mini USB out (http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/digital-cameras/compact-system-cameras/52987/panasonic-lumix-dmc-gf6-review)
- 2012 Mac Mini w/HDMI, Thunderbolt, and 4xUSB connections

Is it absolutely necessary to have a hardware converter in the chain, or is there software (ManyCam, FMLE) that will handle that for me?

Very confused by conflicting info elsewhere on the net, so hoping someone here has an answer. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Mac Mini does not have HDMI input.

GF6 has no video output through USB.

Answer (score 0):

You need extra hardware, probably one of the cheapest adapters for this is the blackmagic ultrastudio mini recorder which does hdmi - thunderbolt.

Comment: But since the question was asked may 2015, I guess the OP found a solution anyways :)